# How to tell if Google Apps Script installable trigger function was called for the same user?

Tags: google-apps-script

Spreadsheet script needs to send email on Edit event **from** the account of the user who made the edits. There are several users working on the file.

Every user of the Spreadsheet once enables an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run the function. Thus, on every edit event trigger from every user is launched - same function called multiple times.

**How is it possible to tell from within that function, if the call was made from the trigger installed by this or some other user?**

---

Observations.

Inside event handler there are basically three Users available:

1. Session.[getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser)
2. Session.[getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser)
3. [event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).user

Three user accounts installed same trigger on the Spreadsheet.

**Test 1.**
Made a single edit under account A. Three calls to the function logged.
EffectiveUser email represented each of the three, while ActiveUser and Event User were both empty.

**Test 2.**
Made a single edit under account B. Three calls to the function logged.
The difference with Test 1 is that AtiveUser and Event User appeared now as the owner of the document.

Still there is no way inside the funciton to tell, when the EffectiveUser email is the account who made the particular edit.

Another path is to save [getUniqueId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger#getuniqueid) of the created Trigger with the user [Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getuserproperties). However I do not see a way to tell which *triggerId* caused the function to launch.

Comment: honestly, dont think this is possible

Comment: @noogui it seems that UniqueID aproach works. There is an undocumented (?) property of the event object: `triggerUid`, which contains the id of the trigger that caused it to launch. I'll post the reply as soon as will have this concept proved in production.